# How do I exclude a property from being mapped

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using the latest version (downloaded today) of the `AutoMapper`.

The command I'm using is like this:

```
Mapper.Map<TypeSource, TypeDest>(source, dest);
```

What I'd like to do is add an option after `dest` to tell it to exclude a certain property from being mapped.

I've looked at lots of examples, but none relate to this way of using the Mapper...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using inline mapping which is the case here so you can configure your mapping like below:

```
Mapper.Map<TypeSource, TypeDest>(source, dest, 
    cfg => cfg.ConfigureMap()
              .ForMember(destination => destination.YourPropertyToIgnore, 
                         options => options.Ignore()));
```

Comment: Thank you. Just what I need ;-)

Comment: As an aside, would .ForMember(source...) work too, and would .ForSourceMember(source...) also work? Do the overloads which take a property name as a string also work the same way?

Comment: ForMember expect first the destination member (Source -> Dest). ForSourceMember is to use when you want to do a reverse member so it expects a source member. (Dest -> Source).